# Refreshing graphics buffer (or something like this) in Jessie

Tags: debian, graphics, intel

I have a Dell Latitude E4200 (Intel graphics) and Debian Jessie.

When under stress, the graphics break to the effect that patterns and fonts get distorted. This picture shows this a little, as it's already got better:

[image]

It can get much worse.

The question is how to refresh the graphical buffers, or something similar. The graphics mends itself when the CPU or/and RAM catches breath. But it doesn't get back to normal completely.

This problem is not only Debian related. In Windows it's much heavier. But I want a solution for Debian.

Comment: You could try switching VTs (Ctrl+Ait+F2 and then either Ctrl+Alt+F1 or Ctrl+Alt+F7), that might repaint the screen. You could also run a memory test (install the `memtest86`, reboot and look for the memory test entry in the GRUB menu).

Comment: Switching ttys doesn't help. I'll try memtest when I reboot. But I think I did that already some time ago.

Comment: Nothing in memtest.